# Object has no method 'spilt' after getting value from attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, attr

I want to use the split method on a variable that was get from attr.

This is the code that I'm trying:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_divs').each(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var ida = id.spilt("_");
       alert(ida[1]);
    });
});
```

But, when I run my code, it throws me an error: Object id_1 has no method 'spilt'.

I have tried to cast the variable to string using *.toString* and *String()*.

Possibly I'm missing something basic here. What would it be?

Comment: id.spilt => id.split ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644215/spilt-is-not-a-function

Comment: `spilt != split` lol :D

Comment: Dude, I have to be retarded -_-

Comment: @KevinB - That's freaking scary, that you actually found a duplicate with the exact same wrong spelling ?

Comment: looks like you spilt a typo into your code. spilt should be spelt split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `split` not `spilt`

```
var ida = id.split("_");
```

On a different note you could just use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_divs').each(function() {
       var id = this.id;
       var ida = id.split("_");
       alert(ida[1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: @roasted Yeah i noticed later.. :)

Comment: That is it, Thanks... Half an our on this !@#$%. So blind i didn't see it -_-

Answer (score 2):

just do

`String.prototype.spilt = String.prototype.split`

:D

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, use *split* instead of *spilt*